# Select random item where item occurs more than three times in table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to select a random item from a table where a value occurs more than three times in that table.

I've got as far as "SELECT userid FROM breadscores ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1", but I'm not sure what to put as a where_condition.

I'd also like to ensure that it's weighted evenly regardless of how many more times than three that the entry occurs. Would I have to use some sort of subquery?

Comment: You should avoid order by rand(). It's terrible on large dataset.

Comment: Fortunately it's only a few hundred entries in size - too big to do manually, but small enough that I'm not worried about performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT userid FROM breadscores GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the `limit 1` (I left it off so you can see the `select` is actually working ;))

```
SELECT counts.userid 
FROM (SELECT count(*) ucount,userid
  FROM breadscores
  GROUP BY userid) counts
WHERE counts.ucount>3
ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: Looks like it works, but the other answer seems to be more efficient. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @Hal Clive - certainly is which is why I upvoted it... but this is an alternative.

Comment: It's good to have alternate ways of doing things - it helps the learning process. Thanks!